# Python outputs type 'Nonetype' when try to add to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nonetype

Here is the code(Running Python 2.7.6):

```
currency_pairs = {'PPC': 10}
print currency_pairs
currency_pairs = currency_pairs.update({'NMC': 50})
print type (currency_pairs)
```

Output:

```
{'PPC': 10}
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Why won't Python add to the dictionary?  I don't understand this.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The method `update` just updates the dictionary but don't return anything (in other words, returns `None`)
In the line

```
currency_pairs = currency_pairs.update({'NMC': 50})
```

you are assigning `None` to `currecy_pairs`. The method itself, will modify the dictionary, so you should call it like this:

```
currency_pairs = {'PPC': 10}
print currency_pairs
currency_pairs.update({'NMC': 50})
print currency_pairs
```

**Output:**

```
{'PPC': 10}
{'PPC': 10, 'NMC': 50}
```